# How to split and find number of 0's in column

Tags: python, csv

I have 14 columns (A-N) in a CSV file I am looking to find how many patients(303 in total) have 0 signs for heart disease this would be in column 14(N) anything above 0 would be counted as ill patients and those with 0 are healthy.

From what I have in my code so far is this. I know I am more than likely doing this wrong so please correct me if I made a mistake.

```
    import csv
import math
with open("train.csv", "r") as f:
#HP is healthy patient IP is ill patients
    for c in f.read():
        chars.append(c)
num_chars = len(chars)
num_IP = 0;
num_HP = 0;
for c in chars:
    if c > 0:
        num_IP += 1
    if c <=0:
        num_HP += 1
```

Comment: Why are you importing the csv module but not using it?

Comment: `f.read()14` ???...Do you think this will read column 14 of your csv file?

Comment: Sorry brain is a bit fried I entered a code that I was going to scratch off this one had a lot of mistakes as for the csv module I'm suppose to get the stuff off the columns give me a second I'll put on the code I was suppose to put up. Though it is similar.

Comment: `c` in this code is always a `str`. Comparing to `0` is not going to work at all in Python 3, and will silently misbehave (treating any `int` as being less than any `str`) in Python 2. It's also kind of silly to do `for c in f.read(): chars.append(c)` when you could just store the contents of the file directly `chars = f.read()` or if you really needed a `list` (you don't seem to), `chars = list(f.read())`. And none of this even uses the `csv` module, even after your update.

Comment: So your question is about how to fix your code but you didn't even post the right code? People are going to have a lot of trouble helping you.

Comment: @Maruis yes you are right and I apologize I try to do all I can before asking, I also haven't slept well this past week had a death in the family and been working around the clock to be able to make the funeral arrangements and missed class so I'm just very behind (putting it as nicely as I can there) So I do apologize my teacher was suppose to go over csv files and how to work them properly but I missed that lecture.

Comment: @ShadowRanger thank you you saved me probably hours of me being frustrated trying to make it work and not knowing why it wouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

```
#turn csv files into a list of lists
with open('train.csv') as csvfile:
     reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
     csv_data = list(reader)

#count the amount of patients with heart problems
count = 0
for row in csv_data:
    try:
        if (row and int(row[13]) > 0):
            count += 1
    except IndexError:
        print("could not find the heart diseases status for the row" + str(row))

print("the amount of patients with heart disease is " + str(count))
```

Comment: When I tried it it said "TypeError: list index out of range. Though thaks for the help I have to ask though what does 
Delimiter do?

Comment: Most CSV files use commas to separate the different fields in each rows. If something else was used you would have to specify that in the CSV file. As for the error you got, that means there was a row that had less than 14 columns. I'll go ahead and update my answer to ignore those errors.

Comment: @Dandy remember that indexing in Python is 0-based so if the required field is column number 14 (counting from 1), then in Python it will be `row[13]`

Comment: @Marius Thanks I forgot that it started as 0

Comment: @Mr.Me As maruis said it seems that I might of got you confused it was 0-13 so there are 13 columns but there when I changed it there was a new error saying "can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly.

would using a str.format fix the problem?

Comment: Oh, Sorry if you look at the error it would say that that is coming from the last line of the code. The count variable needs to be turned back into a string.

Comment: @Mr.Me There is nothing to be sorry about, I'm simply trying to grasp a way to fix the problem. like I stated before I'm not 2 familiar with this so I appreciate the help and am learning more as I read all your comments. So thank you even if you  do get something wrong I can take a look and hopefully see why and how to fix it.